# Prove that for $a\neq0$, $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to \infty}}\left (1+\frac{a}{x}\right)^x=e^a$.

Tags: calculus, limits

**Prove that for $a\neq0$, $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to \infty}}   \left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)^x=e^a$**

Phew, well I don't even know where to start! L'Hôpital's Rule requires the function to be in fraction form, but I'm not sure how to get there as there's an exponent. Something to do with logarithms, but my working out is nonsensical and doesn't make sense to me. It would be amazing if someone could lend some clarity to this question, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know that it holds for $a=1$?

Comment: Hint : $\log(1+\frac{a}{x})^x=x\log(1+\frac{a}{x})=a\frac{\log(1+ah)-\log(1)}{ah}$ with $h=1/x$. Let $ah\to 0$. Do you know the derivative of $\log$ ?

Comment: It is also true is $a=0$.

Comment: @Salcio I just realised! An oversight by the person who made the question, although it might over-complicate things given that logarithms are used to solve the answer.

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you, the first part of your answer helped me solve the question, although I didn't use first principles it seems quite intuitive!

Comment: If you are allowed to use L'Hôpital's rule, then the following solution is probably the easiest. First rewrite the limit as follows:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)^x=\lim_{x\to\infty}\exp\left(x\ln\left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)\right)=\exp\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}x\ln\left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)\right) \, ,
$$
where I have used the notation $\exp(y)$ in place of $e^y$. (The second equality can be justified by the fact that $\exp$ is a continuous function.) Then, write $x\ln\left(1+\dfrac{a}{x}\right)$ as $\dfrac{\ln\left(1+\dfrac{a}{x}\right)}{1/x}$ and use L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: @aayush: If you want further clarification, then don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: @Joe Thanks for the answer, it was very clear for me to understand and the thought process was quite similar to what I ended up coming with.

Comment: @aayush: No problem! I’m glad I could help :)

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $a$ is non-zero. Then $x\to\infty$ implies $|x/a| \to \infty$ and so
$$ \lim _{x\to\infty} \left ( 1+ \frac{1}{\left ( \frac{x}{a} \right )} \right )^{x/a} = e. $$
Conclude the desired result from continuity of exponentiation.

Comment: Forgive me, I'm just trying to make sense of your answer. Why does the exponent on $e$ disappear? And what does the "continuity of exponentiation" entail?

Comment: @aayush: To answer your first question, note that the power is $x/a$, not $x$. It is well-known that $\lim_{y\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)^y=e$. To answer your second question, there is a theorem which states that $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)$ exists and equals $l$, then $\lim_{x \to c}g(x)^a=l^a$. This theorem relies on the fact that the exponential function is continuous.

Comment: @Joe Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This solution may be helpful to you:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can start by rewriting it as

\begin{align*}
\left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)^x
&=\exp\left(\ln\left[\left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)^x\right]\right) \\
&=\exp\left(x\ln\left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)\right) \\
&=\exp\left(a\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)}{a/x}\right).
\end{align*}

Recall now the standard limit

$$\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+u)}{u}=1.$$

Notice how $\frac{a}{x}\to0$ as $x\to\infty$, and so we can use this limit to get that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)}{a/x}=1.$$

Thus, using the continuity of the exponential function, we get that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)^x=\exp(a)=e^a.$$

Answer (score 0):

Many people had different methods to get to the solution and I wanted to share mine as well:

1. $$y=(1+\frac{a}{x})^x$$
2. $$\ln{y}=\ln[(1+\frac{a}{x})^x]$$
   $$\ln y=x\cdot \ln(1+\frac{a}{x})$$
   $$\ln y=\frac{\ln(1+\frac{a}{x})}{1/x}$$
3. $$\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to \infty}}\frac{\ln(1+\frac{a}{x})}{1/x}=\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(\ln(1+\frac{a}{x}))}{\frac{d}{dx}1/x}$$
   $$=\frac{\frac{-a}{x^2}\space \div (1+\frac{a}{x})}{1/x^2}$$
   $$=\frac{ax^2}{(1+\frac{a}{x})x^2}$$
   $$=\frac{a}{1+\frac{a}{x}}$$
4. $\space$ As $x \rightarrow \infty$, $\frac{a}{x}$ will approach $0$ and hence the expression will also approach $a$.
5. Finally, we are left with
   $$\ln y = a$$
   $$y=e^a$$

Comment: You start with $y=y(x)$. Fourth line you establish $\ln y = f(x)$. Then you take the limit on the right hand side, but what makes you think $\ln y = a$ follows? Why is nothing happening on the left hand side?

Comment: Ok I thought about it some more. What should happen here is $$ \lim _{x\to \infty} \ln y(x) = a, $$ which implies $$e^a = \exp \left ( \lim _{x\to\infty}  \ln y(x) \right ) = \lim _{x\to\infty} \exp (\ln y(x)) = \lim _{x\to\infty} y(x).  $$